# Googlebot index strings as URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, indexing, googlebot

On my website I have Javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ratingComment").webwidget_rating_simple({
        rating_star_length: '5',
        rating_initial_value: '',
        rating_function_name: '',
        directory: '/images/raty'
    });
});
```

Googlebot index it & tries to go to URL '/images/raty'. But this URL don't exists, ofcourse.

Can I disable indexing of URLs like this? I get thousands of errors in Google Webmaster due to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent Googlebot or other search crawlers from accessing or making requests to a directory, you can always add an entry to your robots.txt file.

In this case, I might restrict all User Agents with:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /images/raty
```

This will prevent any crawler that respects robots.txt from accessing anything that matches the path `/images/raty`. Note, it's not just that specific path, but it'll include all URLs that matches that string.

You might want to check out [Google's Robots.txt Support Page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en) for more info.